# Is there any way to add variable watch for debugging in xeus python kernel jupyter lab?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

It is like in VBA Excel when I wanna inspect certain value change of a variable in a loop, it would stop when the 'variable == certain value' using 'Add Watch'. But I don't know how to do it in xeus python jupyter lab.